# View exposed filter with month and remove year

Tags: 7, views

I have an issue that needs the help of everyone. I created the page in view to filter the node. I created a filter **Date created** in "view exposed filter" for filter by  **Date created**.

I configured for the Filter granularity is check month,  that filter will display 2 dropbox to me to choose, i.e. month and year dropbox. But I want to display only months option and defaults year is the current year. Do not know if anyone can help me handle the matter.

Thank you very much

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS and jQuery you can achieve your requirement.

**Step 1:** Using jQuery, on change() event of month select list assign current year to year select list.

```
$(".date-month").change(function(){
    //write code to set current year to year select list.
});
```

**Step 2:** Now using CSS, hide year select list.

```
.date-year {
    display: none;
}
```

> Note: You can also achieve the same functionality using Drupal custom hooks.

Comment: How i can use form_views_exposed_form_alter?

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried form_views_exposed_form_alter hook.

Comment: Hi. You can look Month and Year dropbox. It have label is '-Month' and '-Year'. I want change it to '-Month-'. How i can change it?

Comment: To change the label, you can also do it using jQuery. Please always make sure to ask new question, when you have any new thing to discuss.

Comment: Oh. When i set value for year by jquery when i serch not select month it will display validate required month.

Comment: On page load, let the value of Year filter be -year. Set year value to current year ONLY on change event of month select list i.e. when somebody select month.